# How do I customise the content of the navigation bar Methods dropdown in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Even in a small project, and especially for a ViewModel, when I attempt to navigate to a method in the navigation bar, Methods dropdown I get a long list comprising methods but also all variables, observable properties and even all commands and events.

I have tried numerous searches but I am unable to find a way to specify the items type in the list - is this because it is not possible?

I would like to see only methods or specific items I would like rather than everything.

I don't think this was the case in previous versions of Visual Studio e.g. 2019 but maybe this was because I did not use ViewModels in previous versions.

Comment: I don't think there is anyway to customize the navigation bar.